# Making Flexible Search Bar

Tags: css, responsive

I have a little problem with my header i want this:

[image]

search bar to be flexible, and this means that if that orange buttons text becomes larger the search bar must resize so that buttonsdont go down who knows how to do it can you share your experience, and sorry form my English

HTML

```
    <div class="navigation-holder">
        <div id="top-navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-9 no-padding">
                    <input type="text" name="" class="top-navbar-search" placeholder="Поиск по предметам или по именам">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 no-padding">
                    <div class="top-navbar-links">
                    @if(Auth::check())
                        <a href="{{ action('UserController@getIndex') }}" class="top-navbar-links-login">{{ Auth::user()->first_name }}</a>
                        <a href="{{ action('UserController@getLogout') }}" class="top-navbar-links-login">Выйти</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ action('UserController@getLogin') }}" class="top-navbar-links-login">aefaefaefaefaefaefaefe</a>
                        <a href="{{ action('UserController@getRegister') }}" class="top-navbar-links-register">Зарегистрироваться</a>
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="{{ action('PageController@getIndex') }}" class="navbar-brand"></a>

                <button class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="">Обратная связь</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ action('PageController@getAbout') }}">О проекте</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">Рус</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Узб</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Eng</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>






#top-navbar{
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: @brand-blue;

    .top-navbar-search{
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 50px;
        padding: 0 70px 0 20px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #339dd1 url(../img/search.svg) no-repeat 97% 48%;
        background-size: 22px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Light';

        .placeholder({
            color: #fff;
        });
    }

    .top-navbar-links{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
        a{
            padding: 0 10px;
            font-family: 'Light';
            color: #fff;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 50px;
            font-size: 18px;
            min-height: 50px;
            float: left;
            background-color: @brand-yellow;
            .transition(background, 200ms, linear);

            &:hover{
                background-color: #d17a45;
            }

        }
    }
}



#navbar{
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;

    .navbar-brand{
        width: 160px;
        height: 41px;
        background: url(../img/brand.svg) no-repeat center;
        background-size: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 16px;
    }

    .navbar-toggle{
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        span{
            display: block;
            width: 35px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 4px;
            background-color: #393939;
            .transition(all, 200ms, linear);

            &:before{
                content: '';
                top: 23px;
                .bar;
            }
            &:after{
                content: '';
                bottom: 23px;
                .bar;
            }
        }

        &:hover{
            span{
                background-color: @brand-blue;
                &:before, &:after{
                    background-color: @brand-blue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .navbar-nav{
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 70px;

        li{
            display: inline-block;
            &:first-child{
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
            &:nth-child(3){
                margin-left: 30px;
            }
        }

        a{
            display: block;
            line-height: 70px;
            color: @brand-black;
            .transition(color, 100ms, linear);

            &:hover{
                color: @brand-blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide your html and css. or a jsFiddle atleast

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grid, an example:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Search</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Button</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am using grid anyways when text in buttons is big the search bar isn't resizing

Comment: there i provided sorry that in one code block I am not good with stacks editor